# DST issue with java Calendar

Tags: calendar, dst

I am seeing this issue while using Calendar instance to subtract one hour from time when day light saving ends and we transition to standard time.
here is the code:

```
 Date startTime = new Date();// Gives me Sun Nov 06 01:26:16 EST 2016
Calendar temp;
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault(); //Eastern
temp= Calendar.getInstance(timezone);
temp.setTime(startTime);
temp.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -1);
 temp.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Date endDate =  temp.getTime(); // This is still Sun Nov 06 01:26:16 EST 2016
```

The result that I expect in endDate is Sun Nov 06 01:26:16 EDT 2016 instead of Sun Nov 06 01:26:16 EST 2016. I am not sure if this is as designed or not. If I subtract 2 hours, then I see it working fine.
Any inputs on this?

Thanks,
SS

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

You should be using java.time classes rather than the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Calendar` than are now legacy.

Be sure to read the class doc for [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to understand its choice of how to handle the Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-overs.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `EDT` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" );
// of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone)
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2016 , 11 , 6 , 1 , 26 , 16 , 0 , z );
ZonedDateTime zdtOneHourEarlier = zdt.minusHours( 1 );
ZonedDateTime zdtOneHourLater = zdt.plusHours( 1 );
```

Note the offset-from-UTC in each result.

> zdt.toString(): 2016-11-06T01:26:16-04:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdtOneHourEarlier.toString(): 2016-11-06T00:26:16-04:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdtOneHourLater.toString(): 2016-11-06T01:26:16-05:00[America/New_York]

See this code [run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/swjll0).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).